# How to execute a command automatically based on the result generated by the previous command on command line?

Tags: command-line, git

**Example usecase**:

I have a usecase where I clone Android Studio projects using `git clone <urL>` and upon cloning I get all folders from a repo including `.idea` folder.

This `.idea` folder is located inside `repositoryName/.idea` generated after git cloning

This `.idea` folder is not useful for my usecase and most times I have to delete it to import a project into Android Studio otherwise, it shows error.

**What is expected**:

I expect a command which does this:

Clone a GitHub repo and automatically delete the `repositoryName/.idea` folder.

Solution could be Windows based or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell you can clone, the directory and then CD into the latest directory by creation date assuming it is new and then remove the .idea folder. Let's assume you are in C:\projects to start and run git clone from there:

```
git clone url
$folder = gci | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1
cd $folder
Remove-Item .idea
```

The second command auto assigns the value of $folder to the path of the most recently created folder. (presumably the new project folder since you just created it with the git clone command)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Scripts takes `<url>` as input parameter:

Where `<url>` could be `git@github.com:username/repositoryName.git`

This worked for bat files.

**Use**: file.bat `<url>`

```
@echo off

SET url=%~1
git clone %url%
SET %url%repo=%url%
SET %url%%url%folder=%repo%
DEL /S %folder%\.idea
```

or this for bash.

**Use**: sh file.sh `<url>`

```
#!/bin/bash

url=$1
git clone $url

repo=${url##*/};
folder=${repo%.*}
rm -r $folder/.idea
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash this could be

```
git clone <url> && rm -rf repositoryName/.idea
```

The `&&` runs the following command if the previous succeeded.

Further reading is here for "bashing this out:"

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208870/how-do-i-run-a-command-only-after-previous-command-is-unsuccessful-in-bash